# Does torbrowser leave details of bookmarks after deletion of bundle from windows 10

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have read a lot of conflicting info regarding this.  If i delete torbrowser from my pc using windows 10, does tor leave behind traces of bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

Tor browser does not encrypt the bookmarks, so this means that if the tor browser folder just got deleted - and not overwritten by other data - then it can potentially be recovered with recovery tools.

This is why its very important to always use a tool that deletes and overwrites the bytes on the disk where the data was located.
[Bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) is one such application, it also works on multiple platforms.

You can then use this to scrub empty space on the disk if you already deleted something and want to make sure its gone for good, this will then make sure any deleted files cannot be recovered.